# array_search ignores the first value and skips to the second value

Tags: php

I am trying to display the correct weather icon for the correct weather code, but it doesn't seem to work? In the code below, you'll see that I have 2 `wi-day-cloudy`, but with different weather codes (`02d` and `03d`). `array_search` only goes after the second (`03d`) even if strict are set to true.

```
function weathericon($string) {
    $array_icons = Array(
        'wi-day-sunny' => '01d',
        'wi-day-cloudy' => '02d',
        'wi-day-cloudy' => '03d',
        'wi-cloudy' => '04d',
        'wi-day-snow' => '13d'
    );

    return '<i class="wi '.array_search($string, $array_icons, true).'">';
}
```

How can I fix this so it does go after both `02d` and `03d` even if they have the same icon code (`wi-day-cloudy`)?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with another solution that worked better.

```
function weathericon($string) {
    $array_icons = Array(
        '01d' => 'wi-day-sunny',
        '02d' => 'wi-day-cloudy',
        '03d' => 'wi-day-cloudy',
        '04d' => 'wi-cloudy',
        '13d' => 'wi-day-snow'
    );

    return (!isset($array_icons[$string]) ? '-' : $array_icons[$string]);
}
```

Comment: The idea is good. Starting with PHP7, it is a little shorter with return $array_icons[$string] ?? '-';